# TexShop: Create new !TEX TS-program association

Tags: texshop

I have a Python file that I'm currently running through TexShop's configuration for pdftex, latex. I'd rather not enforce this for *every* pdftex file, but use some

```
% !TEX TS-program=mypython_file.py
```

inside the tex files where I want to use it. But how would I tell TexShop to use this? I already tried setting the TS-program as exactly my python file name, and storing the latter in the /Engine folder. It got ignored. What else do I have to take care of?

Comment: Maybe it's easier to create a new Arara rule for this.

Comment: Well, the easiest way to proceed for now was for me to learn Bash and rewrite my script there, create a new .engine file. Alternatively, I could have created n engine file that runs my python file (which then runs another engine).